# intent.hasExtra("meta") throw bad parcelable exception

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi in my app I see an exception in this line of code

```
intent.hasExtra("meta")
```

this is my exception

> Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException
>
> android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2436)
>
> android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2358)
>
> android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2264)
>
> android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:2614)
>
> android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:221)
>
> android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey (BaseBundle.java:269)
>
> android.content.Intent.hasExtra (Intent.java:6002)
>
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.Activity}: >android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a ?Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class Meta

I cannot understand how could this happen I'm just asking for existing of a key in an intent extras but it throws an exception.

For testing, how can this scenario happen? I create a test app and create a parcelable object and check for meta in intent but my app works correctly and does not throw the exception.

```
    //test case
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("META",new A());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: 
intent.hasExtra(\"META\")="+intent.hasExtra("META"));
//this log work without exception so why i get exception in my original app?


static class A implements Parcelable{
    String d="0dsfa";
    int a=10;
    public A(){

    }
    // the order of reading and write parcelable is wrong 
    // but I want to see that's cause of exception, which my test shows 
    // that's not my problem
    protected A(Parcel in) {
        a = in.readInt();
        d = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(d);
        dest.writeInt(a);
    }

    private static final Creator<A> CREATOR = new Creator<A>() {
        @Override
        public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new A(in);
        }

        @Override
        public A[] newArray(int size) {
            return new A[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `readParcelableCreator` throws exceptions with explanations. You should past those as well.

Comment: jeez who approved that edit. it's horrible.

Comment: change Createor from private static to public static

Comment: `the order of reading and write parcelable is wrong but I want to see that's cause of exception, which my test shows that's not my problem` How will you know you're not getting BadParcelableException because of this? The check is supposed to be simple: that the output is the same as the input. Don't try to outsmart yourself by adding complexity.

Comment: I update my question but I don't think that's going to help because I have parcelable creator and I use autovalue.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec "How will you know you're not getting BadParcelableException because of this? The check is supposed to be simple: that the output is the same as the input. Don't try to outsmart yourself by adding complexity"        because it doesn't throw an exception even when parcelabe is wrongly implemented.

Comment: In which case what's the point? Either you do it right and it doesn't throw an exception or you do it in wrong order and it still doesn't throw an exception. That gives you no information.

Comment: yes if it does throw an exception I know that's my problem is parcelable object that I send to my intent now I searching for something else.